# How to add an HTML element found by ID to the body?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add an DOM element that is found by ID into the body tag and remove all ewxisting body nodes.

My solution does not work:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("email");
document.body.innerHTML = ele;
```

Comment: It's already part of the body if you can find it with getElementByID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
document.body.innerHTML = ele;
```

Will interpret `ele` *as a string* and write that string to the document body.  That string is going to be something like `"[object HTMLDivElement]"` (may differ by browser).

> and remove all ewxisting body nodes

It sounds like you're looking for  [`document.body.replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) then?  For example:

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("email");
document.body.replaceChildren(ele);
```

```html
<div>test 1</div>
<div id="email">test 2</div>
<div>test 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.

- Option 1 : clear the content of `<body>` and append your element as a child.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("one");
document.body.innerHTML = ''; // Clears the body inner HTML
document.body.appendChild(el) // Appends your element as a child
```

```html
<div id="one">
 HELLO
</div>
GOOD BYE CONTENT
```

- Option 2 : Replace children of `<body>` with your element.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("one");
document.body.replaceChildren(el); // Replace the body content by your element
```

```html
<div id="one">
 HELLO
</div>
GOOD BYE CONTENT
```

Answer (score 0):

With append or replaceChildren you can reach this.

```js
const tag = document.querySelector('#email');
const w = document.createElement('div');
w.append(tag)
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = '';
document.querySelector('body').append(w);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>Head</head>
  <body>
    <h1>body</h1>
    <div id="email"> EMAIL </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const tag = document.querySelector('#email');
document.querySelector('body').replaceChildren(tag);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>Head</head>
  <body>
    <h1>body</h1>
    <div id="email"> EMAIL </div>
  </body>
</html>
```